# Capturing a screenshot of an embedded video using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, video, video-streaming, screenshot

I am working on a video search engine. Similar to google video. I have noticed that google video has a screen shot from all the videos that they index. I have tried many ways to achieve this with no success. One way that i was suggested is to create an swf that will load the required swf and take a screen shot. however this is not a good solution since i need my video to be indexed automatically.

I have already created the search engine to index all videos. but i am stuck on taking a screen shot.

One thing i have noticed is that the screen shots on google video do not have the play controls of players from various website. This leads me to think that they capture a screen shot from the streaming information and not the flash video.

Does anyone have a clue or a method of how to capture a screen shot of a streaming video using c# Asp.net?

**Edit**

I am not looking to get a movie and convert it to flash and take a screen shot.
I am interested in taking a screen shot of Flash movies on sites like youtube and vimeo.
So what i do is index the internet looking for objects tags which i managed to do. But i cannot seem to find a way to take a screen shot. However google managed to do so with google video.

Answer (score 2):

here is good blog post to play video in asp.net and create thumbnail. It could help you as hint. The writer has provided source code too.

http://ramcrishna.blogspot.com/2008/09/playing-videos-like-youtube-and.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i want to take a screen shot of a flash SWF object that plays the movie. This article explains how to take a screen shot of a movie.

Answer (score 0):

This simple method captures the current screen image into a .NET Bitmap object.

```
private Image CaptureScreen()
{
    Rectangle screenSize = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    Bitmap target = new Bitmap(screenSize.Width,screenSize.Height);
    using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
    {
        g.CopyFromScreen(0,0,0,0,new Size(screenSize.Width,screenSize.Height));
    }
    return target;
}
```